# Synchronizing UI update with PostDelayed()

Tags: android, handler, synchronized

I'm new to Android development, and running into a synchronization issue. I made a simple matching game where you flip two cards over at a time, and try to find matches. What I want to do is flip the previous two cards over if either:

- The user clicks a new card (do it immediately)
- After a certain amount of time, if the user does nothing

I tried to safeguard my "flipIfFlipped" routine by marking it synchronized, and checking to be sure that the card has not already been flipped back, but I still get this double-flipping behavior (my force flip must flip it first, then the timer flips it again, or vice versa).

Here's my method on my CardView (ImageView subclass):

```
    public synchronized void flipIfFlipped() {
        if (this.flipped) {
        this.flip();
        }
    }
```

Here's my force flip at the top of my onItemClickListener, if we clicked a card while two are still up:

```
CardView lastCard = game.getLastCard(); 
if (null != lastCard){
    lastCard.flipIfFlipped();
}

CardView secondLastCard = game.getSecondLastCard();
if(null != secondLastCard) { 
    secondLastCard.flipIfFlipped();
}
```

And here's my attempted delayed flip, later, if we just got mismatched cards:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        clickedImage.flipIfFlipped();
        lastCard.flipIfFlipped();
    }
}, 3000L);
```

Again, I'm a newbie, so I'm sure I'm probably missing something basic.